# Ionic 2 exception handling not working?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to create an ionic-2 hybrid app using angular 2. In that, I have implemented the `ErrorHandler`interface, but when an error occurs, nothing will happen. I don't know if that is the correct way to implement the error handler This is my first app in ionic 2.

This is my app module code here

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import { homePage } from '../pages/home/homePage';
import { MyPage } from '../pages/my-page/my-page';
import { FormsPage } from '../pages/forms/forms';
import { SharedData } from '../providers/shared-data';
import {MyExceptionHandler} from '../validators/myhandler';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2,
    homePage,
    MyPage,
    FormsPage

  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Page1,
    Page2,
    homePage,
    MyPage,
    FormsPage

  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},SharedData]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

my appcomponent

```
import { NgModule,Component, ViewChild,ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';
//import {provide} from '@angular2/core';
import { Nav, Platform, } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';

import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import{homePage} from '../pages/home/homePage';
import { FormsPage } from '../pages/forms/forms';
import {MyExceptionHandler} from '../validators/myhandler';
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyExceptionHandler}]
})

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'

})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage: any = homePage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'gotohomepage', component: homePage },
      { title: 'gotopage1', component: Page1 },
      { title: 'gotopage2', component: Page2 },
      { title: 'forms', component: FormsPage }
    ];

  }

   initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

and my handler page

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

export class MyErrorHandler extends IonicErrorHandler {
  handleError(err: any): void {
  super.handleError(err);//call parent handleError
 }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    alert('ionViewDidLoad FormsPage');
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to override `handleError` function in your custom class.

   `handleError(err: any): void {
   super.handleError(err);//call parent handleError
   // do something with the error
    }`
2. Also you set `IonicErrorHandler` as your provider.Check [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/IonicErrorHandler/) and [this is the github link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/util/ionic-error-handler.ts)

You can either set the provider array as:

```
 providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyExceptionHandler },SharedData]
```

Or I suggest trying to extend `IonicErrorHandler` instead.

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

export class MyExceptionHandler extends IonicErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler{
 handleError(err: any): void {
super.handleError(err);//call parent handleError
// do something with the error
 }
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error"Runtime Error
Can't resolve all parameters for MyErrorHandler: (?)."

Comment: have you imported IonicErrorHandler?

Comment: also ionicViewLoad lifecycle hook wint be called in errorhandler..it is not a component

Comment: ya i have imported a IonicErrorHandler

Comment: you shouldnt be setting providers in app.component

Comment: check the github link..add a constructor

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-errorhandler-override-or-decorate/73783

Comment: still i have  some doubt  @suraj

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: you create a separate ts file in your project like any other class...not sure what you mean..

Comment: same thing i did i have created a seperate file  for error handler

Comment: and where i add this   providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyExceptionHandler },SharedData] line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133062/discussion-between-suraj-and-r-anandan).

Comment: Solid answer. Worked first try for me. They should include overriding parent ErrorHandler with super keyword in the documentation. Thanks for this.